# .change being buggy in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, internet-explorer

I have not been able to reproduce this myself but we have a form where once the value is changed (using .change()) the field will fire off to a save.php to update the value. However users have said that this SOMETIMES will not happen in Internet Explorer, even versions above 6. Seemingly happens more often with a copy paste?

I have looked into the cache and that is not the problem, so the only thing I can think of is that the .change() is not working correctly.

This also only happens on certain fields.

Any pointers as to why this may be will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using change, try *.keyup()* , that should work in IE6 even when ctrl v is clicked and cover you even if focus isn't taken off the input, then you can also use *.focus()* to cover the Right Click + Paste.

Comment: Is this a fairly common problem with IE? as @OverZealous said is using `change` in IE sometimes a hit or miss? I will give both solutions a try. Thanks Guys!

Comment: It depends what option you'd like to use, every time a key is pressed , using keyup will update the save.php each time.

Comment: That seems like alot of hits to save.php though, I will definately try it though. What about `focusout` ? Would `focusout` work for lets say ... Copy & Paste (either way) then click to get to next page? Or would the focus still be on the input box when they click the link?

Comment: focusout will do the same as onchange, it will only effect until focus is lost. keyup is good for stuff like auto-complete searches, if it's only a small script I wouldnt be too bothered

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing the bug where IE won't fire a `change` until focus is lost on radio and checkbox fields.

The solution is to listen to `onclick` for those fields (and those fields only) - this works consistently across all browsers I have tested.